# Using Banach-Alaoglu theorem on $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, lp-spaces

Let $C$ be a bounded closed set in $L^1(0,1)$. Let $h_n$ be a sequence in $C$. Prove or disprove that for every $f\in L^\infty(0,1)$ there is a subsequence $h_{n_k}$ such that $$\int_0^t f(s) h_{n_k}(s) ds\to \int_0^t f(s) h(s) ds$$
for every $t\in [0,1]$ and some $h\in C$.

Comment: It may not be a good idea to use $k$ as a function and an index for a subsequence.

Comment: With that being said, what have you tried?

Comment: I sense that the statement is not true for all $k\in L^\infty$, but it is true for some $k$.

Comment: Note that $L^1(0,1)$ doesn't have a predual, so Banach Alaoglu is not what you want to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$h_n=n\chi_{[0,1/n]} $$
and $f=1$, $C=\left\{h_n\right\}$.

Then $C$ is bounded and closed in $L^1(0,1)$ (since $\|h_n\|_{L^1}=1$ for all $n$), and for any subsequence $\left\{h_{n_k}\right\}$ we have, for each $t\in (0,1]$,
$$\int_0^t h_{n_k}f=\int_0^tn_k\chi_{[0,1/n_k]}\to1$$
Now suppose by contradiction that there exists $h\in L^1(0,1)$ with 
$$\int_0^tf(s)h(s)\,ds=\int_0^th(s)\,ds=1\qquad \forall t\in (0,1] $$
By absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral,
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_0^t h(s)\,ds =0 $$
which is a contradiction.

Notice that if we do not require the equality to hold for all $t \in [0,1]$, but just for e.g. $t=1$, then this counterexample no longer works, as $h=h_n\in C$ (for any fixed $n$) is an admissible limit for any subsequence. I suspect that this weaker statement might actually be true, although it does not seem easy to prove.

Also, it is not hard to check that the same contradiction is obtained if we replace $f=1$ with any $f\in L^{\infty}$ such that 
$$\lim_{k\to +\infty}n_k\int_0^{1/n_k}f\neq 0 $$
(e.g. any continuous function with $f(0)\neq 0$).

Answer (score 2):

As Lorenzo has pointed out in his fantastic answer this statement may be true if we just want the integral convergence to hold on the fixed interval $[0,1]$. What follows is a partial proof of this statement, in the hope that someone can take it over the line, because I find this to be quite an interesting question.

Let $K$ denote the uniform bound of the sequence in $L^1(0,1)$. Note that by Holder's inequality, for any $f\in L^\infty(0,1)$ and $n\in \mathbb N$, we have
$$\left |\int_0^1h_nfdx\right|\leq K\|f\|_\infty.$$
Thus $\left(\int_0^1h_nfdx\right)$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$), so by Bolzano-Weierstrass there exists a convergent subsequence $\left(\int_0^1h_{n_k}fdx\right)$ converging to some $a\in \mathbb R$, with $|a|\leq K\|f\|_\infty$.

What remains to prove is that there exists some $h\in C$ such that 
$$a=\int_0^1hfdx.$$

We note that $L^\infty(0,1)\subset L^1(0,1)$ and $L^\infty(0,1)$ separates the points of $L^1(0,1)$. The Riesz representation theorem thus implies that there exists some $h\in L^\infty(0,1)$ such that 
$$\int_0^1hfdx=a.$$
Unfortunately this method does not guarantee that $h\in C$. I believe, if it is possible at all, some rather subtle tools will be needed to show we can find some $h\in C$.

Comment: Thank your for keeping the discussion open because I believe that this version of the question is actually more interesting. I will just add some thoughts. If $L^1$ were reflexive, then by Kakutani's theorem the result would be true in an even stronger sense (we can use the same subsequence for all $f$). So I think in order to prove the result, we would need some property of $L^1$ which partially replaces reflexivity. If we want to disprove it, we should start from some (possibly explicitly given) sequence $\left\{h_n\right\}$ which contradicts reflexivity.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa  I believe that the statement is far weaker than something akin to reflexivity, because as you say we do not require the subsequences to be independent of $f$. I agree that such sequences are the only possible counterexamples. I'm thinking of asking a new question about this to open up the discussion again. Now that an answer has been accepted I doubt this post will see much traffic.